# Facing issues in aggregation lookup. Need lookup result in same structure as defined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, aggregation

Schema structure

```
 categories: [{
    category: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Category' },
    subCategory: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Category' }]
}]
```

Query

```
 {
                $lookup: {
                    from: 'categories',
                    localField: "categories.subCategory",
                    foreignField: "_id",
                    as: "categories.subCategory"
                }
            },
            {
                $lookup: {
                    from: 'categories',
                    localField: "categories.category",
                    foreignField: "_id",
                    as: "categories.category"
                }
            },
```

Facing issues in aggregation lookup. Need lookup result in same structure as defined.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) for decoding an array, explanation is added in query comment below:

- unwind your `categories` array
- lookup for `category` with `Category` collection
- unwind again because lookup will return an array and unwind will convert into object

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { $unwind: "$categories" },
    {   
        $lookup: {
            from: "Category",
            localField: "categories.category",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "categories.category"
        }
    },
    { $unwind: "$categories.category" },
```

- lookup for `subCategory` with `Category` collection

```
    {   
        $lookup: {
            from: "Category",
            localField: "categories.subCategory",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "categories.subCategory"
        }
    },
```

- group by _id because without `group` lookup will multiple documents
- store `$$ROOT` in root var, because we need to use it for replace root
- `push` categories object that we got from lookup

```
    {   
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id",
            root: { $mergeObjects: "$$ROOT" },
            categories: { $push: "$categories" }
        }
    },
```

- replace new root after merging with root and $$ROOT

```
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: {
                $mergeObjects: ["$root", "$$ROOT"]
            }
        }
    },
```

- remove `root` var because no longer needed

```
    {
        $project: { root: 0 }
    }
])
```

For the explanation purpose i have divided in to parts, you can merge easily as all are in sequence.

Working Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/lKd5-MjcT1K

Comment: @AbhishekBansal Have you checked my answer, is it useful? you can share if your are facing any error.

Comment: Yes, I have seen your answer and is quite impressive but didn't use it in my project as the initial requirement was changed. But no doubt this will help me in future.
Thank you for your time.